# Google is counting the domain home page ("/") as a duplicate of "/index.html"

Tags: google-search-console, duplicate-content, canonical-url

For *only* my index pages, I am receiving this warning in Google Search Console:

> Duplicate, submitted URL not selected as canonical

I know that this occurs because Google is attempting to track both the default landing "page" (i.e. `www.domain.example/`) and the page to which to which `DirectoryIndex` points (i.e. `www.domain.example/index.html`). They are, in fact, the same page, and so the warning is the result of a false positive.

Two questions for our community:

1. Why does Google not conflate these and count them as a single page? Alternately, **is there something wrong with my set up if this has happened?**
2. I can easily force both pages to point to a single canonical URL. But **which is preferable, "/" or "index.html"?**

Comment: "to which it has been redirected" - Are you redirecting from one URL to the other? (But your #2 suggests you are not?) Which URL are you linking to?

Comment: When you visit a web site that ends with a slash, it means you are visiting a directory. Every directory should have an index of the contents within that directory, hence, the index.html file. yoursite.com/ will automatically, first, search for an index file but index.html is also the contents of '/'.

Comment: @Rob Exactly. To me, and the all site visitors, all is working well. My only concern is that **Google Search Console sees this as a duplicate URL.** I would like to have one of these point to the other as the canonical version, instead of marking both as canonical. Does this make sense, or should I alter my approach?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing anything. Do not redirect one to the other because a directory is not a file and index.html is a file.

Comment: I think "redirect" was the wrong word to use. I will clarify the language above. My apologies: I work in an environment where I routinely translate these things for non-tech people, and I think I was stuck in that mode.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`index.html` should not be part of a URL that users ever see.   It is a wide spread web server convention that if you want a page to show up for the directory URL, you put that page into a file called `index.html`.    The reason that you create an `index.html` file is put the content at the directory URL.  `index.html` doesn't say anything meaningful to users.  The URL is always simpler and better without it.

You should never include `index.html` in a full absolute URL for your web site.  It shouldn't be in your sitemap.  It shouldn't be in any links to your site.  It shouldn't be in links within your site.

- Instead of `http://example.com/index.html`, use `http://example.com/`
- When linking on your own site using a root relative URLs, instead of `href="/index.html"`, use `href="/"`
- When linking on your own site using directory relative URLs, instead of `href="index.html"` use `href="./"`

Google is recognizing that you have the same content on two URLs.   Google knows that `index.html` files are meant to show content at the directory.   Google is preferring to index the simpler, better URL.

You ask "Why does Google not conflate these and count them as a single page?"  -- Well, Google is recognizing that those two URLs are the same page and Google is telling you which URL it chose as the one that it is going to index.   Google doesn't usually index multiple URLs with the same content.  See [What is duplicate content and how can I avoid being penalized for it on my site?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site).

This does not indicate a huge problem.   The worst that is going to happen is that some users see the ugly `index.html` in URLs.   It would be better if you linked to the cleaner form and included the cleaner form in your sitemap, but it won't hurt your search engine rankings too much if you don't do it right.   Google is telling you that it is taking care of the issue for you and including the cleaner version in its search index.

Comment: Thank you, Stephen. You have explained this very clearly, even though my opening post may have misdirected others through its obtuse language :-P     I will have my sitemap include `example.com/` and not even mention `example.com/index.html`. It now seems very common-sense – after I had it carefully illustrated to me, haha!