# How to fix duplicate title tags canonical for / vs index.html

Tags: seo, htaccess, canonical-url, homepage, directory-index

I am confused, after scanning by an online SEO tool, it says:

> error duplicate title tags canonical; `https://cleanmypc.co.uk` and `https://cleanmypc.co.uk/index.html`

I have in my .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cleanmypc\.co.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "https\:\/\/cleanmypc\.co.uk\/" [R=301,L]
```

and on my web page https://cleanmypc.co.uk/index.html I have `<link rel="canonical" href="https://cleanmypc.co.uk/index.html/" />`

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: See also: [Google is counting the domain home page (“/”) as a duplicate of “/index.html”](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/122306/google-is-counting-the-domain-home-page-as-a-duplicate-of-index-html)

Comment: Why the trailing slash in the canonical URL?  `/index.html/` is a 404 error on your site.